# Can't Turn off Finder Tabs on Mojave

Tags: finder, mojave, tabs

MacBook Air with Mojave (14.2) and the option in Finder > Preferences > General **NOT** Checked: "Open folders in tabs instead of new windows."

Yet Finder stubbornly opens all new windows in tabs.

For example, I have a folder on the desktop open and in list view. I double click on another folder on the desktop and it opens in a tab in the folder that was just opened.

- I have rebooted
- I have deleted any Finder preference files in
  ~/Library/Preferences and rebooted.
- I have turned the preference on

No joy.

Anyone know where the Finder Tabs preference is stored so I can delete it or have a trick to make it behave?
   (open in tabs), rebooted and turned open in tabs off

Comment: did you try  holding Option+Command then right click on Finder icon in dock, then use Relaunch

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the option only works when opening folders directly from a Finder window. If you CMD-click on Favorites, then a new tab is opened if the preference is On. And a new window is opened if the preference is Off.